# onWillPop not working with flutter provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Back button not working properly...

widget code:

```
onWillPop: () async {
            print(await context
                .watch<ShowOverlayLoaderProvider>()
                .shouldShowOverlayLoader);
            if (context
                    .watch<ShowOverlayLoaderProvider>()
                    .shouldShowOverlayLoader ==
                false) {
              return Future.value(false);
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              return Future.value(true);
            }
          },
```

Provider:

```
class ShowOverlayLoaderProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _shouldShowOverlayLoader = false;
  get shouldShowOverlayLoader {
    return _shouldShowOverlayLoader;
  }

  changeShowOverlayState(s) {
    _shouldShowOverlayLoader = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Not getting any print response also if I try to print the value of `shouldShowOverlayLoader` upon clicking the back button.

Comment: Could you please post the whole widget code?

Comment: Code : https://github.com/theTrivia/howlongtobeat/blob/sf/lib/screens/game-detail/game-detail.dart

Answer (score 0):

Fixed `onWillPop` method:

```
onWillPop:
      (context.watch<ShowOverlayLoaderProvider>().shouldShowOverlayLoader ==
              false)
          ? () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              return Future.value(true);
            }
          : () {
              return Future.value(false);
            },
```